# Does file caching make sense when using Sqlite DB + PHP?

Tags: php, sqlite

does it make sense to use an Filecache when using Sqlite as Database ? Lets say the Database and the Cache is one the same Harddisk (no Raid) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depend if you are using really complex queries.

Like if some of queries take more then 1 minute to process you would prefer to cache it.

After for most common case it is not so useful to do some disk cache. You should investigate some [memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php).